# If the quotient of an ideal is principal, is the original ideal principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a unity conmutative ring and $I \subset J \subset R$ ideals of $R$. Is it true that if $J / I$ is principal, then $J$ is principal? This question has came to me on other excercise in which, in case of being true, it can be applied to solve it, but I do not know how to prove it.

If it is not, is there any conditions that can be imposed on $R, I$ or $J$ to make it true? (appart from supposing that $R$ is a PID)

Comment: I'd be shocked if this were true.

Comment: Doesn't setting $I = J$ with $J$ non-principal already give a huge family of counterexamples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No!

Let $I=(x)\subset J=(x,y)\subset R=k[x,y]$, then $J/I=(y)$ is a principal ideal of $R/I=k[x,y]/(x)$. Suppose for contradiction that $J=(x,y)$ is principal, equal to $(f)$ for $f\in k[x,y]$. Then $f|x$ and $f|y$ so $f=1$  as $\operatorname{gcd}(x,y)=1$. So $J=(1)=k[x,y]$ and $J=(x,y)\ne k[x,y]$, a contradiction. So $J$ is *not* principal.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for your answer

Comment: By the way, $(a,b)/(b)$ is always principal, generated by the image of $a$ in $R/(b)$. So, every non-principal ideal generated by two elements in any ring $R$ gives a counterexample.